# Can't get ADC Pi chip to Work

Tags: raspbian

I am following this tutorial to make my ADC Pi chip work,
http://elinux.org/RPi_ADC_I2C_Python

but when I am running the example code,
**root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ./adc_demo.py**

I am consistently getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./adc_demo.py", line 54, in <module>
    print("1: %f" % getadcreading(adc_address1, adc_channel1))
  File "./adc_demo.py", line 39, in getadcreading
    bus.transaction(i2c.writing_bytes(address, channel))
  File "/home/pi/quick2wire-python-api/quick2wire/i2c.py", line 78, in transaction
    ioctl(self.fd, I2C_RDWR, ioctl_arg)
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Could anyone please help me out ?

Comment: Make sure the `i2c-dev` module is loaded (`lsmod | grep i2c` for a clue).  If not, `modprobe i2c-dev`.

Comment: I think it is already loaded, lsmod | grep i2c gives, 
i2c_dev                 5594  0 ,
i2c_bcm2708             3947  0,
but the error stays